# Kubernetes Installation process guidance

Tags: docker, kubernetes

During the installation of kubernetes, an error is reported when I initialize the master node. I am using the arm platform server and the operating system is centos-7.6 aarch64. Does kubernetes support deploying master nodes on the arm platform?

```
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
```

[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
- The kubelet is not running
- The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
- 'systemctl status kubelet'
- 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker.
Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
- 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
- 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster

6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: W0630 22:53:04.188966   54238 pod_container_deletor.go:75] Container "51615bc1d926dcc56606bca9f452c178398bc08c78a2418a346209df28b95854" not found in pod's containers
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: E0630 22:53:04.189353   54238 kubelet.go:2248] node "master" not found
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: I0630 22:53:04.218672   54238 kubelet_node_status.go:286] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: E0630 22:53:04.236484   54238 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1beta1.RuntimeClass: Get https://192.168.1.112:6443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1beta1/runtimeclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.112:6443: connect: connection refused
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: E0630 22:53:04.238898   54238 certificate_manager.go:400] Failed while requesting a signed certificate from the master: cannot create certificate signing request: Post https://192.168.1.112:6443/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/certificatesigningrequests: dial tcp 192.168.1.112:6443: connect: connection refused
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: I0630 22:53:04.260520   54238 kubelet_node_status.go:286] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: E0630 22:53:04.289516   54238 kubelet.go:2248] node "master" not found
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: E0630 22:53:04.389666   54238 kubelet.go:2248] node "master" not found
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: E0630 22:53:04.436810   54238 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:444: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.1.112:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.112:6443: connect: connection refused
6月 30 22:53:04 master kubelet[54238]: E0630 22:53:04.489847   54238 kubelet.go:2248] node "master" not found

Comment: Have you set SELINUX: permissive? and may i know your node spec? I need more cleary what you have done

Comment: I set SELINUX is disable

Comment: Please take a look m answer below, and look up which step are missing. I've tested all below in my local environment successfully

Comment: Do you use arm platform and CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (altarch)?

Comment: Yeah i'm using same platform as u

Answer (score 2):

To start kubernetes cluster, make sure you have minimum requirement of kubernetes platfrom.

If you want kubernetes cluster with low compute you could discus with me in seperatly.

You need :

1. Docker
2. Compute Node at least 4GB Memory 2CPU.

I will write answer depends on your node.

## Docker

On each of your machines, install Docker. Version 19.03.11 is recommended, but 1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06 and 18.09 are known to work as well. Keep track of the latest verified Docker version in the Kubernetes release notes.

Use the following commands to install Docker on your system:

1. Install required packages

```
yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
```

2. Add the Docker repository

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

3. Install Docker CE

```
yum update -y && yum install -y \
  containerd.io-1.2.13 \
  docker-ce-19.03.11 \
  docker-ce-cli-19.03.11
```

4. Create /etc/docker

```
mkdir /etc/docker
```

5. Set up the Docker daemon

```
cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ]
}
EOF
```

6. Restart Docker

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
systemctl enable docker
```

## Kubernetes

As a requirement for your Linux Node's iptables to correctly see bridged traffic, you should ensure net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables is set to 1 in your sysctl config, e.g.

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF
sudo sysctl --system
```

Make sure that the br_netfilter module is loaded before this step. This can be done by running lsmod | grep br_netfilter. To load it explicitly call sudo modprobe br_netfilter.

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-\$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
exclude=kubelet kubeadm kubectl
EOF
```

1. Set SELinux in permissive mode (effectively disabling it)

```
sudo setenforce 0
sudo sed -i 's/^SELINUX=enforcing$/SELINUX=permissive/' /etc/selinux/config
sudo yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
sudo systemctl enable --now kubelet
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

### Initializing your control-plane node

The control-plane node is the machine where the control plane components run, including etcd (the cluster database) and the API Server (which the kubectl command line tool communicates with).

#### Master

1. Init kubernetes cluster (Running this on master node)

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 192.168.0.0/16
```

Note : I will calico here. so the cidr use 192.168.0.0/16

2. Move kube config to user directory (assume root)

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

#### Worker Node

1. Join other nodes (Running below command from your worker node)

```
kubeadm join <IP_PUBLIC>:6443 --token <TOKEN> \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<HASH>
```

Note : you will get this when you successfully init master

#### Master Node

1. Applying calico

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
```

2. Verify cluster

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/